# Printing stars for a specific number of freq in arrays

Tags: c, histogram

I am still new to C, and I need to figure a way to print the same number of stars as the number of frequencies.

Here's my code:

```
int arrayHistogram(int array[]){
    int i;
    int j;
    int count=0;
    int freq[SIZE];
    char stars[SIZE];
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        count =1;
        for(j = i+1; j < SIZE; j++){
            if(array[i]==array[j]){
                count++;
                freq[j]=0;
            }
        }
        if(freq[i] != 0){
            freq[i] = count;
        }
    }
    //for ( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        //int num = freq[i];
        //stars[i]= '*'*num;
    }
    printf("Value ");
    printf("Frequency ");
    printf("Histogram\n");
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if(freq[i] != 0){
            printf("%5d%10d%10d\n", array[i], freq[i], stars[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I can't multiply `char` by `int` here to print the stars, but I put here just to show where I need to print those stars (i.e. the histogram).

```
My Output:

    Value Frequency Histogram
        7         4       -46
        8         3       126
        4         6        84

Expected output:

      Value Frequency Histogram
          7         4      ****
          8         3       ***
          4         6    ******
```

Comment: you will need one nested loop to print out `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you already know everything to do that i.e. loop.

Simply, loop up to a frequency and print that many stars.

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
loop until freq[i]
    print '*'
end loop
```

It's just an idea. You know how a loop works. Just put a nested loop (i.e. `for` loop) where you need to print the stars. Mind the newline. You need a newline at the end of each line after printing the stars.

---

**UPDATE:**

As observed, you've frequencies up to 10 i.e. a fixed size that you already know. You can simply use a string of stars and then print it using [`printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) with `%.*s` format specifier with field width and string length.

Here's an example ([live code](https://ideone.com/aXUOym)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    const char* stars = "**********";

    const int freqs[ SIZE ] = { 3, 5, 6, 2, 0, 7, 10, 9, 4, 8 };

    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {
        printf("%5d \t %10.*s\n", freqs[i], freqs[i], stars);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    3           ***
    5         *****
    6        ******
    2            **
    0              
    7       *******
   10    **********
    9     *********
    4          ****
    8      ********
```

Answer (score 0):

how about building `char stars[SIZE]` with a loop?

```
int nStars = freq; // in you situation.
for(int i=0; i < nStars;++i)
{
    stars[i] = '*'; // set char i to be '*'
}
stars[nStars] = '\0'; // don't forget to terminate your string
```

you can make a simple utility function `void fillChar(char* buff, char ch, int count);` of it.

**Take Caution** not to exceed the size of the allocated string or bad things gona happen.

Cheers.